# Segmentation Fault syncing in (postgres node adapter) from React Native -> ROS -> Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

Write data from react-native to Realm Object Server by

```
Realm.Sync.User.login('https://xxxx-xxxx-xx.us1.cloud.realm.io/', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx')
      .then((user) => {
        const config = {
          sync: {
            user,
            url: 'realms://xxxx-xxxx-xx.us1.cloud.realm.io/xxxx',
            error: err => console.log(err),
            partial: true,
          },
          schema: [{
            name: 'one',
            primaryKey: 'id',
            properties: {
              id: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
              name: 'string',
            },
          }],
        };
        const realm = new Realm(config);
        console.log(realm.path);
        realm.write(() => {
          realm.create('one', { id: 11, name: 'string' });
        });
      });
```

and when I run my node postgres adapter to sync the data from ROS to postgres it fails saying Segmentation fault. unable to find any detailed logs. I can sync data from ROS to postgres when i write to ROS through **Realm studio** but doesn't work when I write through **react native**. I'm able to sync data from **postgres to react native through ROS** without issue. and also can see data getting written in ROS through realm studio.

Please Refer to this issue [Segmentation Fault syncing from React Native -> ROS -> Postgres](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/656)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was a bug from realm guys. looks like they made fix on update from [2.7.0 -> 2.7.2.](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/656)